# regular expression for Log File capture exact word

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture exact word in log file:

```
/Emergency|Critical|Error|BEA-000331/
```

The problem is when for example I have `Error` to capture 
but this also capture `ErrorUnable`. I want to capture only when it's seen with space. Also i'm looking for `BEA-000331`
but everything with `BEA` is captured.

Answer (score 1):

If you are in perl/ruby add the word boundary marker \b to match only on word boundaries. Also if BEA-000331 must be matched as a single unit try putting that in parentheses :-

```
/\b(Emergency|Critical|Error|(BEA-000331))\b/
```

Comment: hi im getting this error both Content Match Results Content match error First rule of regular expressions: Start simple; get a match; iterate to more complex...

Answer (score 0):

Use `\b`:

> Matches at the position between a word character (anything matched by
>   \w) and a non-word character (anything matched by [^\w] or \W) as well
>   as at the start and/or end of the string if the first and/or last
>   characters in the string are word characters.

`'\bEmergency\b|\bCritical\b|\bError\b|\bBEA-000331\b'`

Depending on what tools you are using you can something like this:

```
grep -Ew 'Emergency|Critical|Error|BEA-000331' log
```

Where the `-w` option forces the pattern to match only whole words.

Comment: hi im getting this error both  Content Match Results 
 Content match error
 

 
 First rule of regular expressions: Start simple; get a match; iterate to more complex...

Comment: From where? What tool are you using?

Comment: im using hp sitescope application